# isAccessibleForFree and cloaking

Tags: google-search, schema.org, cloaking, paywall

I need an advice regarding [`isAccessibleForFree`](http://schema.org/isAccessibleForFree) and cloaking. 
I'm running a subscription based news website which has standard free to view teaser (short description) and the full article.

When user comes to the website, server knows is this a logged in user (with subscription) or free to view user and based on this it renders different content.

Non logged-in page has just the teaser and of course logged in page has the full content of article. By this I mean if user clicks view source he will see just appropriate bit.

By reading Google's guidance ([Subscription and paywalled content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content)) I got confused.

Does this mean that no matter if the user is logged in or not the server should send the full article which will hide content, if user is not logged in just via **CSS**?? Which is of course completely non secure and hackable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that no matter if the user is logged in or not the server should send the full article which will hide content, if user is not logged in just via **CSS**?

No, at least that is not what I take from the linked document. No CSS "hiding" is involved.

You only deliver the "full (paywalled) content" to authenticated/subscribed users **and** verified Googlebots (if you want Googlebot to index the paywalled content). (Note that verifying the Googlebot is more than simply checking the User-Agent. You are also validating the IP address using reverse/forward DNS lookups - which should then be cached for a period.)

It is the schema.org JSON-LD markup in your content that enables Googlebot to differentiate this from *cloaking*.